# Increment value by an incrementing value and output the result

Tags: java

How can I output a list of numbers, so that each next number increments by a value which in turn increments by 1 every time?

In my case I need to output this exact list:

```
0
10
21
33
46
60
75
91
108
126
145
165
```

So that the first value increments by 10, then the result increments by 11, then the result of it increments by 12, then by 13, 14, 15 and so on.

I've tried to achieve this by using for-loops, but obviously haven't got any proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
/**
 * Print List
**/
public static void main (String[] args) {
    /* Initialize Number Value */
    int num = 0;
    /* Initialize Increment Value */
    int increment = 10;
    /* Print First Number */
    System.out.println(num);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        /* Increment Number */
        num += increment;
        /* Print Next Number In List */
        System.out.println(num);
        /* Increment The Increment Counter */
        ++increment;
    }
}
```

Feel free to change the `for` loop iterations from 10 to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
int sum = 0;
System.out.println(sum);
for (int i = 10; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    sum += i;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Technically, this solution works just fine, although results in an infinite loop due to using Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @mikebrsv, you are right about Integer.MAX_VALUE, just used it for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem, and I also feel an adequate introduction to how loops work in Java. You identified that you needed to start incrementing some value by 10 (and subsequently, 11, 12, 13), and that you would need to do that in a loop. This is how you would achieve that

```
int currentNumber = 0;
int incrementValue = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    System.out.println(currentNumber);
    currentNumber += incrementValue++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, too bad I can't accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the increment of the for loop:

```
int increment = 10;
int incrementStep = 1;

for (int i = 10; i < 200; i += increment) {
    System.out.println(i);
    increment += incrementStep;
}
```